# I have A point( lat lng ) and B point Lat long now i want to get c point from 2 coordinates ( intersecting lines triangle)

Tags: geometry, coordinates

I have **A point( lat long  )**
and **B point ( lat long  )**
now I want to get
**c point ( lat long )** dynamic is it possible ?

[image]

Comment: Not without further constraints. Are the green lines in your picture exactly aligned with latitudes / longitudes?

Comment: Sir @jsb yes  exactly aligned with latitudes / longitudes an i have this line with lat long

Answer (score 0):

If the green lines are precisely aligned with the latitude / longitude directions, then this is still ambiguous, but you can cut it down to 2 possible solutions.

Let's say your input points A and B are at coordinates `(lat_A, lon_A)` and  `(lat_B, lon_B)`.

Then, the coordinates of your point C are either `(lat_B, lon_A)` or  `(lat_A, lon_B)`, corresponding to the top left or bottom right corners in the picture below.

[image: Coordinate computations]

To disambiguate between these two options, you need further constraints.